# mkdir in symbolic link to windows mount points to own directory

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, symbolic-link

I'm currently using [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide) to run my linux programs, whilst configuring my home directory I decided to link my Windows Documents folder in it to easily access my data.

However whenever I make a directory inside that symbolic link, the new directory points back to the directory I was just in creating an infinite loop. Example:

```
user@host:~$ ln -s /mnt/c/Users/John/Documents/ /home/Paradoxis/Documents
user@host:~$ cd Documents
user@host:~/Documents$ ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root   0 Feb  1 15:17 .
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root   0 Feb  1 14:36 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 402 Dec 15 13:42 desktop.ini
user@host:~/Documents$ mkdir Hello
user@host:~/Documents$ ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root   0 Feb  1 15:22 .
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root   0 Feb  1 14:36 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root   0 Feb  1 15:22 Hello
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 402 Dec 15 13:42 desktop.ini
user@host:~/Documents$ cd Hello
user@host:~/Documents/Hello$ ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root   0 Feb  1 15:22 .
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root   0 Feb  1 14:36 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root   0 Feb  1 15:22 Hello
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 402 Dec 15 13:42 desktop.ini
user@host:~/Documents/Hello$ cd Hello/
user@host:~/Documents/Hello/Hello$ ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root   0 Feb  1 15:22 .
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root   0 Feb  1 14:36 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root   0 Feb  1 15:22 Hello
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 402 Dec 15 13:42 desktop.ini
user@host:~/Documents/Hello/Hello$ # Goes on forever
```

Is there a way how I can fix this? Thanks

Comment: Have you considered [reporting this to WSL developers](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues)?

Comment: @grawity I assumed I messed something up in Linux itself, but this might be a bug; thanks :)